# How do I allow this if statement to be recognized?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am attempting to create a loop for a login code and have been struggling to format this code to reach the "User Accepted" on line (16). How could I reformat this to allow this code to work correctly?

```
    ##### USER INFO #####
Users = {
  'jc1':123
  ,'jc2':213
  ,'jc3':312
  ,'jc4':321
  ,'jc5':231}
ADPIN = '14726'
##### LOG-IN #####
while True: #Loop Creation
  JK = input('Please enter your username: ') #Username Check
  if JK in Users:
      DK = input('Please enter your password: ') #Password Check
      print('Bug Text Main')
      if JK and DK in Users: #Problem Statement
        print('User Accepted: Hello '+JK+'.') #Unreachable Code
        print('Objective Text')
  else: 
    ToC = input('It appears that the username entered does not exist: Would you like to try again(Press: 1) or create an account(Press: 2)')    #Retry / Account Creation
    if ToC == '2':
      AD = input('Please enter an administrative pin: ')
      if AD == ADPIN:
        add = input('Please enter a username: ')
        tht = input('Please enter a password: ')
        Users.update( {add:tht})
        print('Bug Test Users Append')
    else:               #Restart / Retry
      print('Bug Test Restart')
```

Comment: `if Users[JK] == int(DK):` .. and handle ValueErrors on `int("NoIdeaHaveNoPW")` inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the `Users` dictionary keys are the user ids and the values are the corresponding passwords. Then:

If you reach the following "Problem Statement", you know that `JK` is in `Users` and therefore `JK` evaluates to `True`, so replace:

```
if JK and DK in Users: #Problem Statement
```

with:

```
if Users[JK] == DK:
```

The original statement was testing the password against all the user ids in the dictionary.

The other issue is that your dictionary values are int values while you are inputting strings. So either change your dictionary values to be strings like '121' or change your input statement to be:

```
DK = int(input('Please enter your password: ')) #Password Check
```

But be aware that if the user enters something that is not a valid integer, the above will raise an exception. So you might want to put the above in a `try` block.

Comment: This was useful information however I am still receiving the same error. When I run the code it still does not reach the user accept line.

Comment: Never mind... I realized the issue but this format for checking dictionary is very helpful thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Change Line 13 to

```
  DK = int(input('Please enter your password: ')) #Password Check
```

and the if-statement to

```
  if DK in Users.values(): #Problem Statement
```

Comment: So you login with my password? Why password protect at all?`

Comment: @Patrick Artner That is not my problem, I'm just solving his error, the idea behind his syntax is his ...

Comment: I always try "Password" first ... now your fix breaks the whole program - probably also not your problem?

Comment: @Patrick Artner actually not, cus you don't know how he plant on evolving this code, maybe the problem you are pointing at right now, might be on his todo list for later...or maybe he wasn't aware, but that is his ...I'm fixing the problem he mentioned, and that is reaching his code in the way he is trying to but in a working way...

Comment: Guys im literally one week into coding with python, the syntax is supposted to be a login system using a username and password system. the passwords dont have to be int values if need be they can be changed, same with profile name seriously. jc1-5. I just want to find a way to create a working code using the if statement as I said above. As the code just loops asking for username and password over and over again...

Comment: @Protical Aigth seems legit, so my answer solves your problem, but I guess Booboo has the better answer! Try his